# How to redirect using equals and question mark as characters of the argument in redirectToAction()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I want to redirect the user to another page in my asp.net mvc webapp using

```
return RedirectToAction("foo?productId=" + product.id);
```

but it redirects the user to

```
foo%3fproductId%3dproduct.id
```

I want the app to redirect the user to

```
foo?productId=product.id
```

so the app is able to use the product.id value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_RedirectToAction_System_String_System_Object_) of RedirectToAction:

`return RedirectToAction("foo", new { productId = product.Id });`

Comment: Found the answer right after I asked the question, but this is what I ended up using

Answer (score 0):

```
//How to use RedirectToAction with additional param in MVC

return RedirectToAction("actionName", "ControllerName", routevalue);
```

`RedirectToAction` with parameter:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName","controllerName", new {@productId=product.id});
```

> For Example

If one want to Show error message for `[httppost]` then he/she can try by passing an ID using

```
return RedirectToAction("foo", "YourControllerName", new { @productId= product.id});
```

for Details like this

```
 public ActionResult foo(int? productId)
        {
            if (productId> 0)
            {
                ViewBag.Status = productId + " item is in use";
            }
            return View();
        }

[Httppost]
public ActionResult LogIn(FormCollection form)
        {
            string user= form["UserId"];
            string password = form["Password"];
            if (user == "admin" && password == "123")
            {
               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("foo", "YourControllerName", new { @productId= 1 });
            }
}
```

Hope it works fine.